# Make Android Linear Layout Vertical expand as I type in the edittext inside

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I have an eddittext inside a linear layout at the bottom of my screen, a bit like WhatsApp to write the messages. I can add new  lines in the edit but the linear layout stays exactly the same, I would like the linear layout to expand as I enter more lines. I have a listview above the linear layout

Here is my layout XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".ChatActivity"
android:background="#ffffff">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linlay"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"/>




    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="linlay"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/et_message"
            android:hint="Enter your message" />
```

//I want this Lin Layout to expand as the edit expands vertically

```
    </LinearLayout>


<com.gc.materialdesign.views.ButtonFloat
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_send"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/chatMessageView"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    app:iconDrawable="@drawable/ic_action_send_now"
    android:background="@color/ChatBlue10" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use minheight,

```
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:id="@+id/layout_message"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textBody"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:minHeight="48dp"
            android:hint="@string/send_text"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <ImageView
         ....
         ....
```

else can you show us your xml to unsterdand more your probleme

Comment: @SuperBale did you tested my xml ?

Comment: height: wrap_content was perfect! Sorry for not replying! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

To better answer to your question it's important to know what are all elements that you are using in your layout.xml. Please put all your xml layout file.

Comment: I guess you just need to try android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your lineaLayout

Comment: -1 Sorry, I don't mean to be rude. Oh my god. I've been seeing this a lot lately. This should be a comment! How is this an answer? How would this suppose to help the community? How is this suppose to help the professionals reading on this site? And then you comment your answer? Facepalm